# Should I create a child theme for a parent custom theme?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, parent-theme

I am going to create a mobile version of a desktop theme. *Device Theme Switcher* plugin will use a correct theme based on the client device. The desktop theme is a custom theme. So should I create a child theme for a mobile version or create a totally new theme? Which would be a better option?

I am leaning towards creating a totally new theme because all html of the parent desktop theme will have to be rewritten anyway. Just wanted to confirm.

Comment: To be really honest here, you still expect help after you have asked 8 questions here and even haven't taken the time to leave appropriate feedback on your previous questions. You have recieved some valid answers, but haven't accepted one as of yet. Please take your time to revisit **ALL** your previous questions and leave proper feedback, accepting the answers which solved your issues. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely avoid using 2 different wordpress themes and instead code for a more responsive website with CSS mediaqueries. It has worked out very well for me on the Wordpress websites I created.

If you're not familiar with media queries, here's a very basic rundown.

HTML --

```
<div class="box">hello world</div>
```

CSS --

```
.box { width:800px; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .box { width:450px; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I am aware of what you have suggested but then I thought maybe it'd be even easier if I created a new theme just for mobile devices. On the desktop theme, there are a lot of irregular background images and the client wants a fairly simple mobile version where I can just pull in content and place them on a mobile version.

Comment: I can see your thought process, but also consider that with this theme switching there is now going to be a difference between a mobile device and a really small desktop browser window.